# Checking my proof that $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/(2n - 3) = 0$

Tags: limits, solution-verification

My goal is to prove that the sequence $(x_n)$ defined as $x_n := \frac{1}{2n-3}$ converges and the limit is $0$. In addition to determining if my proof is correct I also wanted to know if there is an alternative way to do the proof, maybe with an inequality that holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, still just using the definition of the limit of a sequence.

My proof:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. By the Archimedean Property there exists some $K_{*} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1/\varepsilon < K_{*}$, therefore $1/K_{*} < \varepsilon$. Let $K = \max\{K_{*}, 3\}$ and suppose $n \geq K$. Then

$$\bigg|\frac{1}{2n-3} - 0 \bigg| = \bigg|\frac{1}{2n-3}\bigg| \leq \bigg|\frac{1}{n}\bigg| = \frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{K} < \varepsilon,$$

where the first inequality holds for all $n \geq 3$.

Comment: This is excellent. Just a small thing: you want $1/\varepsilon < K_*$ instead of $1/\varepsilon \le K_*$, so that the final inequality is indeed strict.

Comment: your proof looks fine.

Comment: @Crostul Thanks for the verification.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for pointing that out. It should now be corrected.

Answer (score 5):

Proof makes sense to me. Another way you can prove it is that if you already proved $\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow 0$, note your sequence is a subsequence of $\frac{1}{n}$ (excluding the first element), and thus it converges to zero since all subsequences of a convergent sequence converge to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Good proof! But here's a similar way to do it, using the theorem that if $ |s_n - s| \le a_n $, where $a_n \to 0$, then $s_n \to s$. (I'll refer to it as Theorem 3.1.9 in the proof because that's what it was named when I first learned it.)

Claim: $\lim(x_n) = 0$.

Proof. We have: $|\frac{1}{2n-3}-0| = \frac{1}{2n-3} \lt \frac{1}{n} \to 0$ for $n \gt 3$. Therefore, by Theorem 3.1.9, $\lim(\frac{1}{2n-3}) = 0$. $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: Why do think it is acceptable to assume that the sequence converges and where does that number $L$ appear in the proof?

Comment: With intuition. Intuitively, I know that lim(1/2n-3) = 0, but I just assume that, and by doing the scratch work, it so happens that it converges to 0. Is my reasoning correct, and is there a way to improve my proof? Also, forgive me for being crass, as I'm relatively new to the site, and I'm really interested in math, but I only know up to Analysis.

Comment: It is not correct to add an assumption to the problem. Not to mention the fact that I don't see *where* exactly you use that assumption.

Comment: You cannot do mathematics use intuition or assumption. Otherwise, I can assume 0.001=0 by intuition. Then prove 1000=0. You can arrive to any wrong result using a wrong assumption.

Comment: Like I said, is there a way to improve my proof then? Thanks guys for being stern and direct, it’s a nice introduction to the site.

Comment: @bobby Your answer doesn't need to assume the existence of $L$. Theorem 3.1.9 doesn't require the assumption that $s$ is the limit of $s_n$, it just proves that $s$ must be the limit. In fact, $L$ doesn't appear anywhere except where you assume it exists! Other than the redundant assumption, this looks fine. +1

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for explaining it to me! I'll remove this sentence then.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} = +\infty$, we can have $u = 1/n$ and proving $$\lim_{u \to 0^+} \frac{3u}{2u + 3} = 0$$ which is the same problem. One way of proving this is to have $\delta \leq 1$, and we'll have $\delta = \min\left\{1, \frac{\varepsilon}{3}\right\}$.